# Adding a .wav sound when maxlength reach his limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm currently finishing a final project. It's a simple form but I wanted to jazz it up with some sounds. I picked a theme and it's Kindred from LoL. I was asked by my mates and reinforced by my teacher to attempt to add a sound when the textarea reaches its limit. However I've been on this for months, I'm not kidding. Can you please help?

```js
function NoMoreWords() {
  //var x = document.getElementById("message").maxLength;
  var x = document.getElementById("message").maxLength = "<embed src='sounds/Kindred_nomorewords.wav' autostart=true loop=true volume=50 hidden=true>";
  document.getElementById("embed").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="All things end..." maxlength="10" size="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  </form>
</p>
```

I can post the full code for you to try out, I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You could trigger a function when you reach maxLength value. And then using html5 Audio() you can play the sound. You want the full example for that?

Comment: Your code seems really incomplete. Your JS function does not end and you don't close the `form` anywhere. Also, I don't think it's good practice to wrap `form` element with `p` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the textarea limit is 50. This is the javascript function you call every time a key is pressed in the textarea. When the length becomes greater then 50 the music will be played. Just assign the relative address in `your/url/here`.

```
<input type="text" id="a" onkeypress="music()" />
<script>
function music() {
            var a=document.getElementById("a").value.length;
            if (a > 50) {
                new Audio('your/url/here').play()
            }
        }
</script>
```